# Header background drawing problem

Tags: bug, design

Since a month now, the banner of both the main site and the Meta site have this strange effect (a dithering problem?):

[image]

It is more apparent on the right side:

[image]

- I'm using Firefox 83.0. In Edge there is no problem. I don't have Chrome to test it.
- Using the Inspector, the problem seems to be (the positioning of) `background-image: url("img/header-background-image.svg?v=fe2fd5316ad9");` of the *.site-header* class. The image seems to be drawn using a simple block of pixels.
- The Dark Reader plugin I use is not the problem.
  Other plugins I use only block scripts (AFAIK) and shouldn't influence the drawing of static images.

**Does anyone else have this problem, or a potential fix?**

Comment: I have noticed this too, it's supposed to be scanlines. Zoom to 80% or 120% and it fixes itself up, which makes me think the background image is not properly configured for certain screen sizes

Comment: You're right: currently it renders fine when on 80% and 120% zoom. Resizing the browser window also has an obvious effect.

Comment: What is your monitor resolution?

Comment: @Nzall 1920  by 1080.

Comment: Still, as mentioned, I've never seen this problem before, so it might have been introduced with the latest Firefox version.

Comment: I don't feel like it's the size, as 1920x1080 is **16:9, the standard screen size,** and when I use this site on my iPhone or iPad it works completely fine.

Comment: Meta site has the same problem: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15825/text-on-footer-on-arqade-meta-difficult-to-read