# Text on Footer on Arqade Meta Difficult to Read

Tags: bug, design

I noticed today that the footer across the Arqade Meta site is difficult to read the text on because of the gray lines.  It's as if the lines are going through the text, almost like a strike-through.

[image: Lines]

The text in the bottom right "site design / logo © 2021 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa. rev 2021.5.11.39266" is especially difficult to read.  This seems to be like this across different browsers (tried Chrome and Edge with same results), on a 1920x1080 display at 100% zoom.

At 125% zoom, it looks absolutely horrible:

[image: 125% Zoom]

I think is has to do with the image being retrieved here, which appears to be these lines:

[image: ImageUrl]

If I edit the page source to exclude this image retrieval, and modify the background color from white to a gray (like all the Meta sites), it looks way cleaner:

[image: ModifiedFooter]

I also noticed the header of the site exhibits similar behavior.

Comment: Are you on 100% zoom or is it zoomed slightly in or out? I have noticed this happen with zoom

Comment: It's not nearly as pronounced for me, it looks like the spacing between the lines is larger in your screenshot.

Comment: If I zoom in to 125%, it looks a lot like your screenshot.

Comment: @Unionhawk I am on a 1920 by 1080 display, 100% zoom

Comment: Related: [Header background drawing problem](//meta.arqade.com/q/15450/28182)

Comment: @Robotnik I would say that's a duplicate actually, so I'll close this.  But would be nice if it was resolved 